# Obscure bug with mouseover event not firing properly before clicking the rendered content

Tags: electron

What happen is that if I open my app and move the mouse around, elements pick up mouseover/mouseout events just fine. However if I use the mouse wheel to scroll the page, the events don't fire if I happen to scroll to a spot where the mouse is actually hovering an element. If I click anything within the window other than the dev console, the events start firing properly upon scrolling over elements.

This is using electron 25.2.0 under win 10, I realize its not the latest version but I'm not comfortable attempting an update given my experience with those and where the project is at.

Does anybody have a clue as to why this would be happening? Perhaps a workaround? Programmatically sending a .click() in the front end doesn't work, I tried that.